Spring Boot Keycloak docker-compose
I am having an issue when my Spring Boot app in Docker container tries to access Keycloak Docker container. I have created them using docker-compose. Here are the files:
version: "3.8"

services:
  psql-db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: psql-db
    restart: always

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      remind-me-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.4

  remind-me:
    container_name: remind-me-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://psql-db:5432/postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=xxx
      - KEYCLOAK_URL=http://172.20.0.2:8989/realms/remind-me
    depends_on:
      - psql-db
    networks:
      remind-me-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3

  keycloak-prod:
    image: keycloak-prod-img
    container_name: keycloak-prod
    hostname: keycloak-prod
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=xxx
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxx
    command: start-dev
    ports:
      - '8989:8080'
    networks:
      remind-me-net:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2

networks:
  remind-me-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
          gateway: 172.20.0.1


applrication.properties file in the Spring Boot app:
spring.application.name=remind-me
server.port=8080

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=xxx

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=false
spring.sql.init.mode=always

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind=TRACE

schedule.frequency=0 0 9 * * *

#John Remindme
spring.mail.host=xxx
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=xxx
spring.mail.password=xxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

#keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=${KEYCLOAK_URL}
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=${KEYCLOAK_URL}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
jwt.auth.converter.resource-id=remind-me
jwt.auth.converter.principal-attribute=preferred_username

#flyway
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.baseline-version=0

#ehcache, second level cache
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml

The error i get is:
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://keycloak-prod:8989/realms/remind-me/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection refused

I can connect to Keycloak via the browser on localhost. Also i get connect to it via Postman and get the token. However the spring boot app in docker throws error.
Thanks!

I'm having the same kind of problem, simple stack of spring boot and keycloak. Realm URL passed in application.properties through an env variable and same IO error.
Did you find the solution ?

I am having the same issue, nothing seems to work

try using the static IP of the container, I had a similar problem and it is due to the execution contexts since the container could be outside the network and you have to point it directly, at least for development, in Windows you can use "ipconfig" to see the ip of the virtual machine

Tnx for the replay. I tried with the change you made but i got the same error. Check the edited docker-compose file
